# Is there a way to specify a name when creating a key in Google KMS via the Python client?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

In the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudkms/v1/python/latest/cloudkms_v1.projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.html#create), you cannot specify a name for the key in the Python client (name is "Output only"). However, with the CLI tools you can specify the name of the key (KEY_NAME here) ala `gcloud kms keys create KEY_NAME --location LOCATION --keyring KEYRING_NAME --purpose encryption`. Is this functionality not available in the Python API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for the new key goes into the top-level parameter called `cryptoKeyId`, and must be provided. The `name` field in the body cannot be provided when creating a key; the only mandatory field is `purpose`, which must be `ENCRYPT_DECRYPT`; then, when the response comes back, the name field will be populated.

Here's a request I just did from the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/kms/cloudkms/v1/cloudkms.projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.create) (on a project I control with a key ring I'd already created). You can see that the new key name is provided as a URL parameter, `cryptoKeyId`. (The `key={YOUR_API_KEY}` is a redaction made by the browser API Explorer UI).

*Request:*

```
POST https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/cloud-kms-demonstration/locations/global/keyRings/test01/cryptoKeys?cryptoKeyId=testKey01&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "purpose": "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT"
}
```

*Response code:* 200

*Response:*

```
{
 "name": "projects/cloud-kms-demonstration/locations/global/keyRings/test01/cryptoKeys/testKey01",
 "primary": {
  "name": "projects/cloud-kms-demonstration/locations/global/keyRings/test01/cryptoKeys/testKey01/cryptoKeyVersions/1",
  "state": "ENABLED",
  "createTime": "2018-03-28T23:17:32.485044241Z"
 },
 "purpose": "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT",
 "createTime": "2018-03-28T23:17:32.485044241Z"
}
```